# Can this be inverted to export lines that match what is written rather than remove?

Tags: powershell

I need to remove every line from a .log file that does not match Invalid Username or Password I got some PowerShell code from a post 4 years ago and just wanted to invert it:

```
get-content "c:\FILEPATH\FILE.log" | select-string -pattern '535 Invalid Username or Password' -nomatch | Out-File "C:\FILEPATH\updated.txt"
```

I expect that the updated.txt only contain the relevant lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just remove the `-notmatch` switch:

```
Get-Content 'c:\FILEPATH\FILE.log' | Select-String -Pattern '535 Invalid Username or Password' | Out-File 'C:\FILEPATH\updated.txt'
```

Comment: Thanks! it seems obvious now :)